# Rails 4 - Toggle Boolean to false on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use Rails 4 to build an app.

The app has 3 models - one for Project, one for Scope and one for Finalise.

Finalise belongs to scope. Scope belongs to Project. Project accepts nested attributes for Scope (and Finalise) and Scope accepts nested attributes for Finalise.

In my finalise model, I have a boolean attribute for :draft. If draft is true, then I want to include a link on the project show page to toggle the :draft to false when the draft is complete.

A SO member has given me some suggestions in the attached (which I have tried to follow, but have not served to toggle the boolean attribute).

In my projects controller, I have:

```
  def new
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new
    @project.scope = Scope.new
    @project.scope.finalise = Finalise.new

  end
```

In my scopes controller, I have;

```
 def new
    @scope = Scope.new
    @scope.finalises.build
  end
```

In my finalises controller, I have a method (which was suggested by another SO user):

```
def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:id])
    @finalise.draft = true
    @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end
```

The finalise route has:

```
 resources :finalises do
   patch '/toggle-draft', to: 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
end
```

The finalise partial show (which is incorporated in the project show) has:

```
    <% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == true %>
           <div class="finalise"> <%= link_to 'Finalise this draft', 
 finalise_toggle_draft_path(:id => @finalise.id),  :remote => true, method: :patch %></div>

    <% end %>
```

When I try this I get an error that says:

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Gabriel (below) has suggested that I might need to link through the associations (so @project.scope.finalise.id). I have tried that formulation and @project.scope.finalise_id. Neither of these work either.

When I try it as:

```
<% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == true %>
    <div class="finalise"> <%= link_to 'Finalise this draft',
                                       finalise_toggle_draft_path(:id => @project.scope.finalise.id),  :remote => true, method: :patch %></div>

<% end %>
```

I get an error that says:
No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>1} missing required keys: [:finalise_id]

When I try:

I get an error that says:

```
<% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == true %>
    <div class="finalise"> <%= link_to 'Finalise this draft',
                                       finalise_toggle_draft_path(:id => @project.scope.finalise.id), :action => 'toggle-draft',   :remote => true, method: :patch %></div>

<% end %>
```

No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>1} missing required keys: [:finalise_id]

When I try:

I get this error:

```
<% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == true %>
    <div class="finalise"> <%= link_to 'Finalise this draft',
                                       controller: "finalises", action: "toggle_draft",
                                       finalise_id: @finalise_id,
                                       :remote => true,
                                       method: :patch %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>"53", :finalise_id=>nil, :method=>:patch}

Thank you

Comment: link_to uses 'GET' so you need to specify the method e.g. link_to "Finalise this draft", toggle_draft_path(@finalise_id), method: :patch

Comment: Thanks Margo, I added 'method: :patch' to the end of that link_to segment, but I still get a routing error that says: No route matches [GET] "/toggle-draft"

Comment: if you run rake routes, you'll probably see that the route is named finalise_toggle_draft, so you need to use finalise_toggle_draft_path in the partial

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'm now getting this error: No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:finalise_id]

Comment: did you pass the id, finalise_toggle_draft_path(@finalise_id)

Comment: I've tried to do it in my link - I've updated the question with the current fields. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: sorry I didnt clock that you're in a projects partial, presumably coming from the projects_controller? You'll have to explicitly set the controller and action.  I cant remember the exact syntax, link_to "text", controller: "finalises", action: "toggle_draft", finalise_id: @finalise_id. Look up link_to in the rails guide.

Comment: Actually Margo, I'm still stuck. I have tried to link by reference to the controller but I still get an error. I've updated the question with the current problem. Thank you

Comment: You need a show method in your projects controller which sets the @project variable as in the new method. Then you can use that variable in the view to get the id for the finalise path.What's the project/scope relationship - have_many or has_one? That will dictate how you access a project's Scopes and Finalises.

Comment: Each project has one scope. Each scope has one finalise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in projects_controller

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

in the projects show view

```
<%= link_to 'Finalise draft', finalise_toggle_draft_path(@project.scope.finalise.id), method: :patch
```

You should be able to use the named route and pass the finalise id which you can get from @project. You'll have to be careful how you get the finalise model in the finalises#toggle_draft method, check how your params are named, probably finalise_id, and not id. It would be good to read up on nesting resources and how to pass variables between controllers.

Comment: Hi Margo, I've tried the id as both '@project.scope.finalise.id' and '@project.scope.finalise_id', but in both cases, I get an error that says: Couldn't find Finalise without an ID

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working (using Margo's guidance):

finalises partial:

```
<div class="finalise">
  <%= link_to 'Finalise draft', finalise_toggle_draft_path(projectid: @project.id, id: @project.scope.finalise.id, finalise_id: @project.scope.finalise.id), method: :patch %>
</div>
```

Finalises_controller

```
  def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:id])
    @finalise.draft = false
    @finalise.finalised = Time.now
    @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(Project.find(params[:projectid]))
```

Comment: That's great that you got it working. I didn't give you the whole solution because when you figure out how to debug and solve the problems, you'll be able to solve future issues more quickly. In the partial, you can just do link_to "Finalise draft", finalise_toggle_draft_path(@project.scope.finalise.id). Then in the toggle_draft method, @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:finalise_id]). Run rake routes in the console and you'll see what params are expected as part of the route. Since you need the project instance to redirect to, you are correct in passing it in the params array.

Comment: Good luck with your project!

Comment: I tried to change the link and toggle_draft method as you suggested but now I get an error when I try this that says: Couldn't find Project without an ID

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting the error when you try to redirect to project_path. Have you passed the project_id as a param? Altho you don't need to, you can get it from the finalise instance. redirect_to project_path(@finalise.scope.project.id). You need to read up on how associations work and use the console to practice.

Comment: I tried that, but I then get an error that says: No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>37} missing required keys: [:finalise_id]

Comment: I thought you said it was working. Maybe you should start a new question and post the code that is not working, formatted. I'm confused as to what is working and what isn't.

Comment: I think I'll just go back to the way I had it earlier. I'll try this again when I can understand better what the various bits are doing. Thanks again - I'm sure your suggestion is useful - perhaps there are problems else where that cause this route to fail

Answer (score 0):

`@finalise_id`is not defined... You can gat the `id` through the relation `@project.scope.finalise.id`

```
<% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == true %>
   <div class="finalise"> <%= link_to 'Finalise this draft', finalise_toggle_draft_path(id: @project.scope.finalise.id), method: :patch  %></div>
<% end %>
```